# sending flow.variables to twilio function

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

In Twilio Studio I'm setting a number of variables. I then need to send them to a function. I'm using `{{flow.variables}}` as a parameter to the function. The result I'm getting in the function is

```
{
  All_VARS: '{childcare=yes, camp=yes}'
 }
```

Why is this formatted as a string with `=`? I would expect `{childcare: 'yes', camp: 'yes'}`
when I send each variable separately with `{{flow.variables.<key>}}`I get what I would expect

```
{
  campVar: 'yes',
  childcareVar: 'yes' 
}
```

But I don't want to send all the flow set variables individually as parameters, it seems that I should be able simply use `{{flow.variables}}` but the return value is not usable. What am I missing?